# Android Studio вылетает когда я открываю раздел design у xml файла

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk

Android Studio вылетает всегда когда я открываю раздел design в xml файле. Я пробовал переустанавливать кучу раз, удалять папки .idea, .gradle, файлы с расширением .iml, много раз делал Invalidate Caches / Restart, заново импортировал проекты, я ставил разные версии от 4.0 до самой последней, переустанавливал SDK, ставил gradle последней версии в отдельную папку, менял расположение программ на разных дисках,  и всё безуспешно. Вылет происходит на всех шаблонах при открытии файла xml. Вылетает не сразу а после небольшой загрузки design. Я ничего не меняю в файлах, но оно всё равно вылетает, по-дефолту так сказать, помогите решить эту проблему пожалуйста.

Comment: Вот! Заменил файл и все, перестало выкидывать https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68577130/android-studio-arctic-fox-2020-3-1-crashing-while-loading-xml

Comment: @user471832 после обновления студии так и фиксил эту ошибку, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Я кажется разобрался с этой ошибкой.
Для тех кто в будущем столкнется с чем-то подобным:
Если я запускаю проект и открываю файл xml который имеет в себе design (например activity_main.xml), то программа падает. Если не открывать этот файл то всё окей. Даже запускать можно. Решение следующее: нужно зайти в ваш проект, при этом главное чтобы xml файлы (подобные тем, что я описал выше) были закрыты. Затем запускаете класс MainActivity с отладчиком (ставите точку останова а потом shift+F9) и затем нужно немного пройтись (возможно это вообще не обязательно) по файлам с помощью F7 (шаг с заходом) и затем открыть файл activity_main.xml (или любой подобный ему) и вуаля! Он загрузится и вас не выкинет. После этого можно работать. Даже можно выйти и зайти в проект и дальше не должно уже вылетать, но после перезагрузки нужно будет повторить этот процесс. Не знаю с чем это вообще связанно, но как мне кажется проблема в том, что нечто не даёт файлам .xml (то есть вкладке design) загружаться и программа начинает падать с неизвестным исключением. И чтобы это решить нужно как-то запустить этот файл.